# Use of moved value error even with use of cloned()

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out why I'm receiving an error about a moved value for this code segment:

```
fn get_names(v: Vec<(String, usize)>) -> Vec<String> {
    v.iter().cloned()
        .map(|(name, _value)| name)
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!(("Herman".to_string(), 5));
    println!("running");
    let names = get_names(v);

    assert_eq!(names, ["Herman"]);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

I was reading [this](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html) weekly rust article and noticed this code block

```
fn get_names(v: Vec<(String, usize)>) -> Vec<String> {
    v.into_iter()
        .map(|(name, _score)| name)
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!( ("Herman".to_string(), 5));
    let names = get_names(v);

    assert_eq!(names, ["Herman"]);
}
```

The syntax makes sense to me, but why would someone want to move out a vector and invalidate `v` ? Why would you not just create a vector `names` and not steal from `v`? I attempted modifying the program to only copy the names but i'm getting the error:

```
src/main.rs:13:22: 13:23 error: use of moved value: `v`
src/main.rs:13     println!("{:?}", v);
                                    ^
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:62 note: in expansion of print!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:58 note: in expansion of println!
src/main.rs:13:5: 13:25 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:10:27: 10:28 note: `v` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<(collections::string::String, usize)>`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:10     let names = get_names(v);
                                         ^
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `tutorial`.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you did not change the argument of the function to receive a pointer to the original vector, so it still reveives it as a moved value. So change this line:

```
fn get_names(v: Vec<(String, usize)>) -> Vec<String>
```

into this one:

```
fn get_names(v: &Vec<(String, usize)>) -> Vec<String>
```

You'll have to change the call accordingly: `get_names(&v);`.

Additionally, instead of using `cloned()` in the iterator that clones the whole tuples, you might iterate through the pointers and clone just the strings. In this case will not make much difference, but if the object in the vector were more complex it might matter. Something like this:

```
fn get_names(v: &Vec<(String, usize)>) -> Vec<String> {
    v.iter()
        .map(|&(ref name, _value)| name.clone())
        .collect()
}
```

Don't forget the `ref` into the lambda match expression, because you cannot take ownership of the borrowed members of `v`. And don't forget the `&` because you are iterating a pointer, so you get pointers to the tuples.

Also, note that you can use the original `get_names()` function without invalidating the vector. Just write `get_names(v.clone())`!

Comment: I'm very new to rust so thanks for clearing those things up. So not passing a vector by reference will **move** the value? Not create a copy and pass that?

Comment: Your second point is incorrect—it’s not `iter.clone()`, it’s `iter.cloned()` which clones the values in the iterator, so for an `Iterator<&(String, usize)>` it will clone the `&(String, usize)` to `(String, usize)`, which is acceptable.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: In rust there are types that implement the trait `Copy`. Those are considered trivially copiable, so a `let a = b;` or a function argumment will make a copy. Those that do not implement `Copy` will not be copied but moved. If the type can be non-trivially copied, then it will implement the `Clone` trait and you will have to explicitly call `clone()` to copy it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Oh, right, I didn't notice that. I'll correct the answer.